# How is the file starting with "Gradle_" in Android Studio's .idea/libraries generated?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to know how is the [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaxJK.png) starting with "Gradle_" in Android Studio's .idea/libraries generated? and what is the generation rule? and how to generate control by humans?

Answer (score 1):

These files are generated by Gradle itself for each Gradle dependency on your project. The more dependencies you have, the more files are generated. The **Gradle_** files follow the following structure:

```
.idea/libraries/Gradle__groupid_artifactid_version.xml
```

There is no "control" over the files that are created. They are generated by gradle plugin automatically during compile time.

These files will contain paths to the downloaded JAR for each dependency. Normally saved on:

```
//$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/
```

See this as a map between the dependencies on your **build.gradle** and your machine storage.

Comment: In addition to that, "Adding a Dependency" in gradle is similar to "Adding an external .jar file" inside your Project. Just like we used to do in earlier days (netbeans or eclipse). So basically, a dependency acts as a url and when you build a project without internet connection, it fails sometimes. That's why it is mandatory to have an internet connection unless you have checked "build offline" option in the settings.